# Making sense of hair_key coordinates

Tags: python, particles, hair

I am trying to convert **hair_key.co_local** to world coordinates. As I understand it, every hair particle has a bunch of hair_keys (type:ParticleHairKey) that represent strand segments. The ParticleHairKey type has two coordinate fields:

- co - **always (0,0,0) on read; writing does nothing**
- co_local - **read produces non-zero vectors; write DOES have some sort of
  an effect**

So my guess is, **co** field is not implemented  / supported and I have to work with **co_local** instead.

according to the docs [ParticleHairKey](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_0/bpy.types.ParticleHairKey.html) **co_local** is "Location of the hair key in its local coordinate system, relative to the emitting face". and there is **co_object** method that returns key location (I assume in object coordinates). No matter what I tried however, the resulting coordinate doesn't seem to map to world coordinates in any meaningful way.

For example, I have a single strand of hair with 3 segments. **particle.location** here is already interpretable - if I put 3d cursor at that position, it matches particle location in the viewport (see pic).

```
obj = bpy.data.objects["gen82"]
psMod = (obj.modifiers)[1]    
ps = obj.particle_systems["ParticleSettings"]

for m, particle in enumerate(ps.particles):
    print("particle location", particle.location)
    bpy.context.scene.cursor.location = particle.location
    for k in range(0, len(particle.hair_keys)):
            print(f"key {k}", particle.hair_keys[k].co_local)
```

Moves 3d cursor as expected.

[image]

and produces following console output

```
particle location <Vector (0.0953, -3.7172, -0.6447)>
key 0 <Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000)>
key 1 <Vector (-0.0036, 0.0030, 0.1666)>
key 2 <Vector (-0.0073, 0.0060, 0.3332)>
key 3 <Vector (-0.0109, 0.0090, 0.4998)>
```

As you can see, **hair_key.co_local** seems to match description from the docs - it gets progressively farther from (0,0,0) as key index increases. But I have real difficulty working with those values. I tried calling **co_object** and transforming to world coordinates, tried offsetting by **particle.location** etc. - nothing produced world coordinates. Is there a way of transforming this coordinate to object or world coordinates ?

Comment: Are you using 2.77?  AFAIK this is different  in 2.8 using the depsgraph (can  post an answer if interested in answer for 2.8,)  Recommend  a simple plane, off global centre eg (1, 1, 1),  example with a couple of hairs and results you obtained for each coord type.  From local_co  desc one would assume will need  a space matrix centered on face center aligned with face normal (tricky). In 2.8  co returns the world coord

Comment: I am using 2.82. Thanks for drawing my attention back to **co**. I googled why it is always zero vector and found this gem https://developer.blender.org/T60083

Comment: Added 2.8 answer.  Assumed you were on 2.77 re docs link above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use evaluated object in 2.8+**

Example for 2.8+ adds an empty at each hair key location. *Note: since it adds an empty via op, test on an object with lowish hair count*

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
dg = context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
# evaluated object
ob = context.object.evaluated_get(dg)
mw = ob.matrix_world

for p in ob.particle_systems[0].particles:
    for k in p.hair_keys:
        bpy.ops.object.empty_add(location=mw @ k.co)
```

Comment: as a follow up, i also want to modify hair_key location.  I figured this probably can't be done through evaluated_depsgraph and i will have to somehow compute my desired hair_key locations in co_local coordinates?